# How to use arrays along with polymorphism?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, methods, polymorphism

Ok so let's say I have an abstract Employee class, 3 classes that inherit from

```
Employee(Commission, Salary, and Hourly)
```

Employee includes

```
name
employeeNumber
gender
```

and the ones under it include things like `getHourlyWage` or `getSalary`. Then I have a driver class with menu with options for the user to choose. And lastly I have a `EmployeeManager` class.

In the Driver class one of methods, that sorts all the employees by name, is called on like this:

```
EmployeeManager em = new EmployeeManager();
em.sortName();
```

now what do I do in the EmployeeManager class??
first i made the array:

```
private Employee[] employees = new Employee[100];
```

So how would I sort this, or first how do I even add an employee with a method that is called:

```
addEmployee(int si, String first, char g, double amount)

int    si    =   1 if the employee is a salary,
                 2 if the employee is hourly, 
                 3 if commission
string first =   name
char   g     =   gender
double amount=   wage, salary, or rate-depends on what kind of employee.
```

Your help would be greatly appreciated!!

I think I did the employee, salary, hourly, commission, and driver correct. I just don't know how to connect them with this EmployeeManager.

Comment: Please show what you have already done and ask a specific question.

Comment: Were the answers helpful or not? Hard to determine your problem with 0 feedback.

Answer (score 3):

All of the objects `Commission, Salary, and Hourly` extend the superclass `Employee`, so when adding them to an array is as simple as this:

```
/**
 * Adds an Employee object to the employees 
 * array at index i. Note: this method doesn't
 * check if there is already an Employee at index i
 *
 * List item
 * @param index The index to add the Employee object at
 * @param e     The Employee object to add
 */
 public void addEmployee(int index, Employee e)
{
    employees[i] = e; 
}
```

This method will work because all of the subclasses `Comission`, `Salary`, and `Hourly` can be generalized to an `Employee` superclass object.

It would be much easier to use an `ArrayList<Employee> employees` then you can ignore indexes altogether and just use the `add(E e)` method in the `ArrayList` class to append an `Employee` object to the list.

```
List<Employee> employees = new ArrayList<>();

public void add(Employee e)
{
   employees.add(e);
}
```

For sorting you should have you `Employee` class implement the `java.util.Comparable` interface and override the `compareTo(Object o)` method.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I think you will find this link helpful: [Java Sorting: Comparator vs comparable](http://www.digizol.org/2008/07/java-sorting-comparator-vs-comparable.html)

The sample shown there uses an Employee class and a List instead of an array. The sorting is solved using comparator and comparable.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you want to use an array instead of the Collections framework.

You would need to iterate through your employees array and set each to a new Employee.

It would look something like this

```
 for (int i = 0; i < employees.length; i++) {
      employees[i] = new Employee();
 }
```

Then, you could go on and add employees

```
 public void addEmployee(int si, String first, char g, double amount) {
     if (numberOfEmployees < employees.length) {
          employees[numberOfEmployees++] = new Employee(si, first, g, amount);
     } else {
          //double the size of the array...
     }
  }
```

Given, your Employee class would also require a constructor like that, which would be:

```
 . . .
 Employee(int si, String first, char g, int amount) {
     this.si = si;
     this.first = first;
     this.g = g;
     this.amount = amount;
 }

 Employee() {
     //empty constructor..
 }
 . . .
```